# How to stop animation which is available by default in dae or scn file?

Tags: ios, animation, scenekit

Today I tried to load different 3d models in my test project and found that some objects are baked with animations. So if I convert .dae file in .scn file animation still works on object but I can't really see an option to disable it.

In some cases in Node Inspector I can see some animations in Animations section but sometimes I can't see it there so there is no clue how I can remove it.

How can I stop it or totally remove animation in scn file if it is present by default?

Comment: Did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop all the default animations in a dae file you can loop through all the animations in a file and stop it. Check the code below.

```
for key in node.animationKeys where node.animationPlayer(forKey: key) != nil 
{
  let player = node.animationPlayer(forKey: key)
  player?.stop()
}
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do this in 2 different ways:
1- stop the animation when its loaded but that would be at last frame

```
                for key in node.animationKeys where node.animationPlayer(forKey: key) != nil
                {
                    let player = node.animationPlayer(forKey: key)
                    player?.stop()
                }
```

2- Reduce the speed to 0 so the animation would stop at 1st frame

```
                for key in node.animationKeys where node.animationPlayer(forKey: key) != nil
                {
                    let player = node.animationPlayer(forKey: key)
                    player?.speed = 0
                }
```

So you can Choose The one that fits for you.